# Question on a C# Homework Problem, please

Tags: c#

Question is:
Write a program that reads data into an array of type int.  Valid inputs are from 0 to 10.  Your program should determine how many values were inputted.  Output a list of distinct entries and a count of how many times that entry occurred.

I have so far:

```
using System;  
using System.Collections;
namespace ConsoleApplication25
{
class Program
{
   static void Main()
    {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        string inValue;

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value from 0-10");
        Console.WriteLine("To end the program, type 11");
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter Value:", i);
            inValue = Console.ReadLine();
            i = int.Parse(inValue);
            list.Add(i);
            list.Remove(11);
            list.Sort();
        }
        int[] c = list.ToArray(typeof(int)) as int[];

        foreach (int value in c)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("There are {0} values.", list.Count);

        }
    }
}
```

Where I'm stuck at is displaying a count of each value.  I have tried setting up an if with a counter, and setting up cases with breaks and have been unsuccessful.  We haven't started using LINQ yet.  Any suggestions or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Jason

Comment: Ixnay on the `ArrayList`.  That's a deprecated class (provided for backward compatibility only) which has been completely replaced by the new generic collections for 6 years now.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: No, the `ArrayList` class is actually not deprecated. It's practically obsolete, but still not marked as obsolete (for some reason).

Comment: @Guffa: Either way, it shouldn't be used in new code, and any professor who is teaching it should be immediately suspended and sent to brush up on his skills.  .NET 2.0 and generics were released in November 2005 (so only five years ago, not six as I said, but the beta was publicly available 10 months before that which is close enough to six years), there's no excuse whatsoever for still teaching using `ArrayList`.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Yes, of course. I was just pointing out that the `ArrayList` class is not actually deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Dictionary<int, int>` to store value and count of how many times it occured. Short example:

```
Dictionary<int, int> values = new Dictionary<int, int>();
...
Console.Write("Enter Value:", i);
inValue = Console.ReadLine();
i = int.Parse(inValue);
if(values.ContainsKey(i))
{
    values[i]++;
}
else
{
    values.Add(i, 1);
}
...
```

Comment: An array would be much better than a `Dictionary` for this particular case (the keys are integral and consecutive).

Comment: I think that showing almost a complete solution for questions marked as homework is not the most useful thing to do...

Comment: It's not a complete solution, but one of the ways to solve problem. Look at the comments and you will find out that there are other (even more better) solutions and it's not necessary that author of the question will choose my one.

Answer (score 3):

1. The way to continuously get inputs from the user is by using a *while* loop, not a *for* loop in which you change *i* all the time. The code should look like:

   ```
   int i = 0;
   while (i < 11)
      get i, put it in the array
   ```
2. There's no reason to sort the array list, and there's DEFINITELY no reason to sort it every time you get a new input.
3. If your input is limited to being 0..10, setup an 11-elements array, go over the items you got as your input, and add to the count. Pseudo-code should be something like:

   ```
   foreach input
      count[input]++
   ```

   Then you'll have the result in each *count* cell.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

Look at [generic dictionaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) for the data structure that will hold both the data for inputs and the number each occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Just to recapitulate, your current approach is to add all entered numbers into a list and then sort the list, so that you get something like 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4. Then you would like to find all unique items in the list and their count.

To do that, you can iterate over the array and

- remember the current value your're reading
- remember the number of times the value appeared so far

then, when the current value changes, you'd print the previous value and the number of times you've seen it. This will definitely work and you should be able to finish the homework this way.

A few unrelated notes:

- It is better to use `List<int>` instead of `ArrayList`, because then you don't need to convert it to `int[]` - you can just work with the list and use `list[i]` to get integer values out of it.
- You should call `Sort` only once after you read all the inputs
- Using `for` loop to read items, you'll only read 11 (fixed count) of items
- Instead of always trying to remov the value 11, you could only call `Add` if the value is other than 11.

As others mentioned, you could use `Dictionary<int, int>` to count the number of items "as you go", but that's a complete change of the approach. I think it is a good idea to finish what you started doing...

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array to store counts instead of the actual integer and use the indexs of the array as the values 0 - 10.  Then when you output the unique values you can just check which indexs dont have count = 0;  For instance, array[1] stores the count for input value 1.

Answer (score 0):

Some tips:

- Don't use the `ArrayList` class, it's practically obsolete. Use a `List<int>` if you want to store a list of integers.
- Your looping logic doesn't work properly. If you enter the value 10, it will be increased to 11 at the end of the loop and exit. Instead you should use a `do {} while()` loop where you exit if the value is 11.
- Don't remove the value 11, instead avoid adding the value if it's 11.
- If you use the approach to sort the list, do that after the loop instead of sorting it over and over.
- You can either keep a list of integer pairs to keep track of values and the number of occurances, or you can keep all values in a list, sort it and then count occurances when you show the result. A `Dictionary<int, int>` is good for keeping the list of integer pairs.
- As the valid values are limited to 0..10, you could also use an array with eleven items to count the number of occurances. When you show the result you skip the values where the count is zero.